# google sheets stop script 'delete duplicate row' from turning all formulas to value and deleting only duplicate in col A:A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As mentioned in the title, I have to stop this script 
From turning all the formulas to value and deleting only the duplicate line of column A: A

```
  function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  if (actualSheetName == "Feuille 1" )  { 
    if (e.range.getColumn() == 1){
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[0] == newData[j][0]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}}}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? It would also be helpful to provide a "before and after" view of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working code is here ^_^
the formula of B4 is `=max(A:A)+1`
if you delete a row or insert a new row it will give here the value of B4 wich is the bigest number of A:A columns + 1 and delete the duplicated empty rows in A:A

```
function onEdit(e) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
if (actualSheetName == "sheet 1" || actualSheetName == "sheet 2")  {
if (e.range.getColumn() == 1)  {
  if (e.value == '' || e.value == null) { 
    var B1Value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B4").getValue();
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();    
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A' + row.toString()).setValue(B1Value);
    }}}{
  var sheet=e.range.getSheet();
  var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  var d=0;
  if (sheet.getName()=="PI-Analy attentes") { 
    if (e.range.columnStart ==1) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        if(newData.indexOf(data[i][0])==-1) {
          newData.push(data[i][0]);
        }else{
          sheet.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
        }}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looked to me like you were trying to make this a onEdit() function so here it is:

In order to get this function to work you must edit a cell in column1. (i.e. you must actually change one of the cells in column one)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet=e.range.getSheet();
  //e.source.toast('flag1');
  var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  var d=0;
  if (sheet.getName()=="Sheet1") { 
    //e.source.toast('flag2');
    if (e.range.columnStart ==1) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        if(newData.indexOf(data[i][0])==-1) {
          newData.push(data[i][0]);
        }else{
          sheet.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Note: you can't test this script in the normal way by running it from the script editor.  You must supply with an event object.  I normally just debug it by editing the appropriate page to generate the onEdit() trigger.

This won't delete blank rows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet=e.range.getSheet();
  //e.source.toast('flag1');
  var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  var d=0;
  if (sheet.getName()=="Sheet1") { 
    //e.source.toast('flag2');
    if (e.range.columnStart ==1) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        if(data[i][0]=='')continue;
        if(newData.indexOf(data[i][0])==-1) {
          newData.push(data[i][0]);
        }else{
          sheet.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working but he is deleting every empty value in the down cell's A:A
i think that he is deleting empty cell because they have the same '' value

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fwVpMm6DGkW1UNzAykgZjX6cQs8FWRwa5I2N9yBsiMc/edit#gid=0)


i have a table in this sheet when i add a row i want cell in 'A' get the number in cell D1
if i delete all the line continents then A get the value in D1 //i have a problem there that all selected line have the value of "D1"
if i add more than one rows i whant the others get deleted but one and A take the value from cell D1

Comment: It seems to me that onEdit() may not be a good choice for this problem.  The problem is definitely more complex than you question suggest.